# TemplaVoila Container with date based output

Tags: typo3, templavoila

I have a TemplaVoila section (Slideshow) with multiple containers.
Each container is a slide for the slideshow.

I want to define a start and stop date for every slide (= Container).
But i don't know how i could achieve this.

Is there a system solution present?

Or do i have to define two textfields "Date start" and "Date stop"? 
But then: How do i control, if the slide (Container) is shown based on today's date?

I already tried to find a solution in TVs docs and by asking Google, but nothing helped by now.